# How can i send multiple queries in jaydebeapi in python (Netezza JDBC)

Tags: python-3.x, jdbc, jaydebeapi

How to send multiple queries in single execute statement for example simplified version of my query is (which i am trying to execute using jaydebeapi )

Create temp table tempTable as
select * from table1 where x=y;

select * from tempTable ;

UPDATE : I am using Netezza JDBC

Comment: It depends on whether the JDBC driver supports multi-statement executes. If you have a particular JDBC driver in mind please [edit] your question to specify.

Comment: Thanks @Gord , I am using Netezza jdbc . I could not find anything on their website

Comment: Probably not, because the JDBC API is not intended for executing multiple statements together. BTW: I don't understand your example. When would selecting into a temp table and then selecting from that temp table be simpler or better than just selecting directly?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  it is a simplified example to illustrate the case .. in my real sql I have multiple temp tables and big final pass to join them all

Comment: Can't you just disable auto-commit and execute them individually? Maybe Netezza has anonymous procedure blocks or something like that?